# In kotlin android tailrec function returns 0

Tags: android, kotlin, tail-recursion

I tried to use this tutorial [youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H_oGi8uuDpA). I have a function as follows:

```
fun fact(x:Int):Int{
    tailrec fun factTail(y:Int, z:Int):Int{
        return if(y == 0) {
            z
        } else {
            factTail(y - 1, y * z)
        }
    }
    return factTail(x,1)
}
```

and this function is called in oncreate as:

```
var abc = fact(5)
Log.i(TAG, "5! = $abc")
```

When the app outputs log it shows like this:

```
I/MainActivity: 5! = 0
```

Can anyone point out what is wrong here.

Comment: I tried it with the code you provided, and got `5! = 120`.

Comment: Same. Got `5! = 120`.

Comment: Idem, I got `5! = 120` in the kotlin REPL

Comment: I cleaned and then re ran. It got me the desired result. Don't know what went wrong before.

Comment: Your code workings fine

Answer (score 1):

You code is right and you definitely get **0** for multiple result more than **MAX_SIZE** of **Int** value. You can get Int max size with:

```
Int.MAX_VALUE
```

So if this y * x cross `Int.MAX_VALUE = 2147483647`, fun will return **0** to you.
For number bigger than **16** func will return minus number and for greater than **33** it will return **0**. you can check this by:

```
for(x in 5..50){
    log.i("$x! : ${fact(x)}")
  }
```

So you can handle this by changing variable from Int to Long

```
fun fact(x : Long) : Long {
     fun factTail(y : Long , z :Long):Long {
         return if (y == 0L)  z
         else return factTail(y-1 ,y*z)
        }
        return factTail(x ,1)
   }
```

But Long also have its limitation. Hope you get the point.